# Erros ao inserir dados na tabela

Tags: java, web-service

Trata-se de um exercício simples, com intuito de armazenar 5 informações no banco: `nomeCliente`, `nomeProduto`, `pesoProduto` (informado pelo cliente), `valorProduto` (valor padrão de `1.20`) e `valorFinal` (resultado final de `pesoProduto` x `valorProduto`).

Com estas informações, ele não está armazenando no banco Java, acusa este erro:

> Erro de sintaxe. Encountered "From"

**CalcularReciclavel.java**

```
package com.service.reciclavel;

public class CalcularReciclar {

    private String nomeCliente, nomeProduto;
    private double pesoProduto, valorFinal, valorProduto;

    public CalcularReciclar (String nomeCliente, String nomeProduto, double pesoProduto, double valorProduto) {

        this.nomeCliente = nomeCliente;
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
        this.pesoProduto = pesoProduto;
        this.valorProduto = valorProduto;

        this.valorFinal = this.pesoProduto * this.valorProduto;
    }

    public String getNomeCliente() {
        return nomeCliente;
    }

    public void setNomeCliente (String NomeCliente) {
        this.nomeCliente = nomeCliente;
    }

    public String getNomeProduto() {
        return nomeProduto;
    }

    public void setNomeProduto (String NomeProduto) {
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
    }

    public double getPesoProduto() {
        return pesoProduto;
    }
    public void setPesoProduto (double PesoProduto) {
        this.pesoProduto = pesoProduto;
    }

    public double getValorFinal() {
        return valorFinal;
    }
    public void setValorFinal (double ValorFinal) {
        this.valorFinal = valorFinal;
    }

    public double getValorProduto() {
        return valorProduto;
    }
    public void setValorProduto (double ValorProduto) {
        this.valorProduto = valorProduto;
    }

    public double gerarValorFinal() {
        this.valorFinal = this.pesoProduto * this.valorProduto;
        return this.valorFinal;
    }

    public void gerarNota(){
        System.out.println("Total" + valorFinal);
    }
}
```

**Reciclavel.java**

```
package com.service.reciclavel;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


@WebService(
    name = "Reciclar",
    serviceName = "ReciclarService")
public class Reciclar {

    private static final String banco = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Reciclavel";
    private static final String usuario = "root";
    private static final String senha = "123456";
    private Connection conexao;
    private PreparedStatement adicionar;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "converterCreditos")
    public CalcularReciclar converterCreditos
    (
        @WebParam(name = "nomeCliente") String nomeCliente, 
        @WebParam(name = "nomeProduto") String nomeProduto,
        @WebParam(name = "pesoProduto") double pesoProduto,
        @WebParam(name = "valorProduto") double valorProduto
    )

    {        
        try{
            conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(banco,usuario,senha);
            adicionar = conexao.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO from Produtos nomeCliente, nomeProduto, pesoProduto, valorProduto, valorFinal");

            adicionar.setString(1, nomeCliente);
            ResultSet resultado = adicionar.executeQuery();

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CalcularReciclar unidadeUm = new CalcularReciclar(nomeCliente, nomeProduto, pesoProduto, valorProduto);
        unidadeUm.gerarValorFinal();
        return unidadeUm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sintaxe da tua query esta errada por isso acusa esse erro.
a sintaxe para inserir:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

e na tua query tens `INSERT INTO from`, é de notar a key `VALUES` esta faltando.

terias de ter algo do tipo:

```
INSERT INTO Produtos (nomeCliente, nomeProduto, pesoProduto, valorProduto, valorFinal)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?);
```

[Segue este exemplo para mais alguma duvida](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement)